# Why can't I flag some answers as very low quality?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

I'm just working through some flags, and I notice that some answers allow a choice of NAA and VLQ (among others), but some particular questions don't allow VLQ.

For example, for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20861926/2065121), which I think shouldn't be "Not an answer" (because it is, it's correct, it's just very poor on content), so I'd like to flag it as "Very low quality". However, the flag options I'm shown are just these:

[image: flags]

Where has the "Very low quality" option gone? It's ok for many other answers.

Comment: Seems like you can't flag upvoted posts as low quality.

Comment: @juergend Ahhh, I see, so an upvote implies it can't be low quality? I didn't think of that, thanks.

Comment: Simple fix, in this specific case: downvote, then you can flag as VLQ.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Simple fix worked fine :-) However, that will presumably only work if there's just a single upvote? Oh and I didn't see the dupe, sorry, I've added my close vote.

Comment: @RogerRowland of course, you can always call for help in chat ([Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) for example, or language-specific chat room) though.

Comment: @everyone It's interesting that this old question of mine from Jan 2014 has been marked as a duplicate of a question asked yesterday! I didn't know I had such foresight :-)